# How to hardcode java used by maven on windows

Tags: java, maven

I know that maven uses `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to start itself. But I cannot change that variable due to lack of administration priviligies (security policy in company). I have Oracle JRE installed which is used by maven currently. I'm running on Windows 10.

I want to hardcode my maven to use specific JDK folder in order to run itself. The one solution I'm working on is to hardcode that in `$MAVEN_HOME\bin\mvn` file but I cannot to do so. As when I'm trying to add something like:

```
set JAVA_HOME="E:\ProgramFiles\java\jdk8"
export JAVA_HOME="E:\ProgramFiles\java\jdk8"
JAVA_HOME=`E:\ProgramFiles\java\jdk8`
```

in that file it still points to installed JRE as I can see from the output of `mvn -version` command.

> `Apache Maven 3.5.0 (ff8f5e7444045639af65f6095c62210b5713f426; 2017-04-03T22:39:06+03:00)
>   Maven home: E:\ProgramFiles\apache-maven-3.5.0\bin\..
>   Java version: 1.8.0_131, vendor: Oracle Corporation
>   Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131
>   Default locale: ru_RU, platform encoding: Cp1251
>   OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"`

Question is: how I need to change my `mvn` or `mvn.cmd` files from `$MAVEN_HOME\bin` in order to use desired hardcoded JDK version? Or is there another solution to that (as I need to run `mvn` command from anywhere - and it need to use specific jdk), except changing environment variables?

Comment: Maybe there's a workaround for the environment variable. If you go to the Control Panel -> User Accounts you should be able to see "Change my environment variables" on the left hand side. When you click that you should see "Environment Variables" window and the top pane (which contains env variables only your user can see) should be editable. There you can set JAVA_HOME, M2_HOME or whatever you need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Linux you can do the same by editing/creating the `mavenrc` file.

```
vi ~/.mavenrc
```

with some input like:

```
export PATH
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home
export PATH=${PATH}:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

> I'm running on Windows 10

There can be a similar file(haven't tried that) created at `%HOME%\mavenrc.bat` with the appropriate definition.

***Edit*** : Thanks to @Robert for pointing it out, for windows its

```
%USERPROFILE%\mavenrc_pre.cmd
```

file that you need to modify/create.

Comment: I don't have that file

Comment: @TolegenIzbassar You can create one in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use export command in windows.
What you could do is, edit mvn.cmd file and define your own MAVEN_JAVA_HOME at the beginning of the file.

```
set MAVEN_JAVA_HOME="E:\ProgramFiles\java\jdk8" 
echo %MAVEN_JAVA_HOME%
```

and replace all JAVA_HOME with MAVEN_JAVA_HOME in your mvn.cmd

Comment: The OP doesn't have permissions to edit this file, as he said "The one solution I'm working on is to hardcode that in $MAVEN_HOME\bin\mvn file but I cannot to do so. As when I'm trying to add something like:"